How to make client-side cookie auth (swell-js) work with SSR rendered pages (Next.js, app router)
I'm building a headless e-commerce Next.js app with Swell, which only provides session management via their Frontend API. I've set up a CSR route for sign-in, where upon successful sign-in, you can retrieve a cookie from swell.session.getCookie() containing the session token, and use await swell.account.get() to read the user object (null if not signed in).
The challenge I'm facing is how to manage this session and check the user's authentication server-side. For example, upon successful login (client-side), the user is redirected to the shop page (server-side-rendered), where, as a "b2b" customer, they should see products with discounted prices. How can I verify the validity of the session cookie and ensure it hasn't been tampered?
Retrieving the cookie client-side (sign-in route)
const useSignIn = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()
  const ref = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)

  const handleSignIn = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setIsLoading(true)

    await login(email, password)
    const isAuthenticated = await getSessionCookie()

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      router.push('/shop')
    } else {
      ref.current?.reset()
    }

    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  return { setEmail, setPassword, ref, isLoading, handleSignIn }
}

export default useSignIn

I can read the cookie server-side like this:
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
 
export default function Page() {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const theme = cookieStore.get('sessionCookie')
  return '...'
}

But how can I validate this cookie and ensure it's safe to use for server-side operations? I don't understand how the flow here needs to be. I guess it needs to work like a 'proxy' sort of.
